# Bitmap to byte[] using Fopen

Tags: c#, image

I am trying to write a code that extracts pixel color values for each pixel in a bitmap file. For such purpose I have imported the bmp as a bitmap object and I have used Bitmap.GetPixel(x,y) method but it was not fast enough for my application. One of my colleagues gave me an advice; I think I can use fopen to open the file itself, parse the byte data to an array. Do any of you have any idea? Using fopen method is not a must, I can use anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not that easy. You need to convert different formats to your target format from raw data and that's not an easy job. At least this is how much I know. You can use `byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes('file.bmp')` to get your data, but I have spoken about formatting.

Comment: The fopen() function isn't any faster or different from FileStream or File.ReadAllBytes() or Image.FromFile().  Focus on using unsafe pointers, *that's* the alternative for GetPixel().  Use Bitmap.LockBits(), there are a ton of google hits out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either unsafe code block or you can utilize the [Marshal class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I'd solve this way:

```
public static byte[] GetBytesWithMarshaling(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int height = bitmap.Height;
    int width = bitmap.Width;

    //PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb => B|G|R => 3 x 1 byte
    //Lock the image
    BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    // 3 bytes per pixel
    int numberOfBytes = width * height * 3;
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[numberOfBytes];

    //Get the pointer to the first scan line
    IntPtr sourcePtr = bmpData.Scan0;
    Marshal.Copy(sourcePtr, imageBytes, 0, numberOfBytes);

    //Unlock the image
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return imageBytes;
}
```

Comment: This was the first answer, and it worked perfectly. Thank you. But I was not able to understand what marshal class is about, and what lockbits method does, could you please explain them briefly?

Comment: 1, Lockbits => During the lifetime of the objects their position in the memory could be changed, for example after a garbage collection. To prevent this behaviour the bitmap is locked/fixed in the memory. I think It works like the fixed statement.
2, Marshal is a static class with bunch of methods to interop between managed and unmanaged code, allocate unmanaged memory, etc.